# How to also Ignore the Parent sample generated by the Transaction Controller along with it's children samples?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am using JMeter 5.5 to put load on some webpages.
I have some webpage navigation flow recorded and I am using The Transaction Controller with the "Generate parent sample" checkbox checked to represent a webpage navigation (load). Underneath the Transaction Controller are the some HTTP Request samplers with "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" checked.

I want to ignore the first and last minute of script execution so I am using a JSR223 Postprocessor with code to conditionally ignore the samples based on the current time in the execution.

[image]

This works well if I don't use the Transaction controller, but when I use the prev.setIgnore() function and the sampler being ignored is underneath a Transaction controller with the "Generate parent sample" checkbox checked, then in the "View Results Tree" listener (and also in the JMeter Dashboard) I get an empty parent sample with `Load time:0; Connect Time:0; Latency:0`. This impacts my metrics in the final generated report.

[image]

Is there any way to ignore the Parent sample as well (remove it from the reporting) or can I achieve the goal in a different way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to replace `prev.setIgnore()` with `prev.getParent().setIgnore()`

---

In general ignoring samples with Groovy is not something I would recommend to do as it causes extra overhead, I would rather suggest using

- either [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/)
- or [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeterpluginscmd)
- or use `jmeter.reportgenerator.start_date` and `end_date` properties in case of using [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

Comment: `prev.getParent().setIgnore()` is throwing this exception: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method setIgnore() on null object`. Any thoughts?  

For the other solutions, I will definitely consider them. Thanks!

Comment: The reason I want to ignore those samples at runtime is because I use a backend listener to directly send results to an InfluxDB at runtime. And I'd like to send them already formatted, so that I don't need to do any other modifications on the data from InfuxDB.